# sql table linking order

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

SQL join general concept:

I have 2 tables 
staff 1000's of rows,
StaffUnitAllocation 10 rows linked to staff

Is there a difference in performance / good practice in the order they are linked in the query:

```
select s.FullName from staff s 
join StaffUnitAllocation sa on sa.StaffUsername = s.Username
where sa.UnitID = '3'

select s.FullName from StaffUnitAllocation sa
join staff s on sa.StaffUsername = s.Username
where sa.UnitID = '3'
```

Both give the same result

Comment: Have you checked the query plan? I'd assume that since it's exactly the same query the plans would be identical - I tried this just now with a couple of my own tables and the query plan was identical. It depends on the join you are doing, but an inner join should produce the same result either way round so you'd expect the plan to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a difference in performance?*

No, SQL is a declarative language so there's not much that can be said about the execution plan based on the query itself. It depends on all kinds of factors, and first and foremost the inner workings of the DBMS, in this case sql-server.

*Is there a difference in good practice?*

Readability is one of the hardest, but also one of the most important things to accomplish while writing SQL queries. Following decent code conventions helps a lot with this. For this particular situation a good practice is to start with the table from which most columns are selected.